# Can an `<iframe>` hold multiple pages inside of it?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am creating a Wordpress plugin that if possible, I would like to link to a series of pages to an outside website (an affiliate login), instead of re-building a replica of the same pages inside of the plugin.

My thought was to do this inside of an `<iframe>`, but since there are several pages, I do not know if this is possible, or if it's even a good idea for other reasons.

I'm thinking it might be better to re-build the pages inside of the plugin.  It sounds like there could be a ton of problems trying to do it with an `<iframe>`.

Comment: make a new html page on your server, but several iframes in it and show that page in your initial iframe :D - a single iframe itself can only hold a single document

Comment: There's only one `src` attribute allowed. Use it well.

Comment: @Jaak Kutt, how can I make a separate `<iframe>` inside of the primary one?  You are saying to embed each page separately as an `<iframe>` after the opening tag?

Comment: in your plugin you would still have one iframe <iframe src="a_file_on_your_server_with_multiple_iframes_in_it.html"></iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a single iframe can only point to a single source - so make that source have several iframes instead - make a new html file in your plugins folder

like `yourdomain.com/path_to_your_plugin/new_iframe_holding_file.html`

in that file put as many iframes as you want show up in your plugin and in your plugin code point the src property of your iframe to that file

Comment: @Jak Kutt, I think I'm catching on....so the first HTML file will actually "mimic" the outside web page.  Then I would create a separaate `<iframe>` for each link I want to show, and those iframe links would be stored in the new HTML file I create, right?

Comment: @Jak Kutt, thank you....I will try this.  Is there any other reason that I should not do this from inside of a Wordpress plugin?

Comment: yes ofc you could make your plugin output the html content for the new_iframe_holding_file for example when called with a $_GET param of your choosing

Comment: @Jak Kutt....thank you.  Your answer has helped narrow down some choices. If you were building, would you take the more robust path of building the interface from inside the plugin?  The reason for outside linking is because I'm connecting to an affiliate membership account.  So in my opinion, building from the inside out would be the "high road" on this, even though it might take more time and skills to build it.  In your opinion would you build from inside out, instead of using `<iframe>`?

Comment: sadly I know too little about your project to make a suggestion about the design choices - you could write a better description and formulate a new question for the community :)