# Embedding multiple iframe players causes JS to be downloaded multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed, soundcloud

I sometimes include multiple Soundcloud players (for different songs) on a page. I noticed that it does slow down the loading and the Google "speed score" of the page ([PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights)) because each new embedded `iframe` reloads *the same* Javascript multiple times! (I saw this with the Chrome Developer Tools, "Network" tab).

For example: the following code will download 4 times the same Javascript code.

**Question: how to load the Soundcloud JS only once and display 4 players for 4 different songs on the same page?**

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/426202317&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false"></iframe>
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/426202317&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false"></iframe>
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/426202317&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false"></iframe>
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/426202317&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=false"></iframe>
```

---

I noticed a similar behaviour for Youtube embedded `<iframe>`, here is a screenshot from PageSpeed Insights:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I beleive Iframes can only point to one source, however I think you may find this post useful. [Can an `<iframe>` hold multiple pages inside of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458941/can-an-iframe-hold-multiple-pages-inside-of-it)

Comment: The question is not really if an `iframe` can hold multiple pages, but more, how to embed multiple instances of such players correctly, without having 5 times the same script to be redownloaded.